# Change an object value from another method

Tags: java

Following problem:

I want to change one value to another, but from a different method. the full code (as requested) is as follows:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class main {

    public static void about() {
        JDialog aboutWindow = new JDialog();
        aboutWindow.setTitle("About kingfisher a0.0.3");
        aboutWindow.setSize(300, 600);
        aboutWindow.setModal(true);
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu control = new JMenu("Control");
        JMenuItem quit = new JMenuItem("quit");

        quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                aboutWindow.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        control.add(quit);
        menubar.add(control);
        aboutWindow.add(menubar);
        JLabel name = new JLabel("kingfisher");
        aboutWindow.add(name);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //Defined window dimensions
        JFrame controlpanel = new JFrame();
        controlpanel.setTitle("kingfisher a0.0.3");
        controlpanel.setSize(500, 400);
        controlpanel.add(new JLabel("The angels have the blue box"));
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        //defining menu groups
        JMenu windows = new JMenu("Windows");
        JCheckBoxMenuItem chat = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Chat");
        JCheckBoxMenuItem filetransfer = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Filetransfer");
        JCheckBoxMenuItem settings = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Settings");
        windows.add(chat);
        windows.add(filetransfer);
        windows.add(settings);
        JMenu control = new JMenu("Control");
        JMenuItem quit = new JMenuItem("Quit");

        quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        control.add(quit);
        JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
        JMenuItem support = new JMenuItem("Support");
        JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
        about.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                //HERE!
                aboutWindow.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
        );
        help.add(support);
        help.add(about);
        menubar.add(control);
        menubar.add(windows);
        menubar.add(help);
        controlpanel.setJMenuBar(menubar);
        controlpanel.setVisible(true);
    };
};
```

`aboutWindow` has been defined in the same class, but not in the `main` method but in in the `about` method. How do i address it correctly?

My current solution (not working at all) is in the `main` method, I have marked it with a comment.

Comment: This question is unclear. What value are you trying to change? Please post the code for the "about" method or explain the problem better.

Comment: updated and added entire source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making `aboutWindow` a class variable (it's also a good practice to rename your class to camel case `Main`):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main
{
    public static JDialog aboutWindow;

    public static void about () {
    Main.aboutWindow = new JDialog();
    Main.aboutWindow.setTitle("About kingfisher a0.0.3");
    Main.aboutWindow.setSize(300,600);
    Main.aboutWindow.setModal(true);
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
            JMenu control = new JMenu("Control");
                JMenuItem quit = new JMenuItem("quit");
                    quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                            Main.aboutWindow.setVisible(false);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                control.add(quit);
            menubar.add(control);
        Main.aboutWindow.add(menubar);
    JLabel name = new JLabel("kingfisher");
    Main.aboutWindow.add(name);
    }

    public static void main (String args[]){
    //Defined window dimensions
    JFrame controlpanel = new JFrame();
    controlpanel.setTitle("kingfisher a0.0.3");
    controlpanel.setSize(500,400);
    controlpanel.add(new JLabel("The angels have the blue box"));
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        //defining menu groups
            JMenu windows = new JMenu("Windows");
                JCheckBoxMenuItem chat = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Chat");
                JCheckBoxMenuItem filetransfer = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Filetransfer");
                JCheckBoxMenuItem settings = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Settings");
                windows.add(chat);
                windows.add(filetransfer);
                windows.add(settings);
            JMenu control = new JMenu("Control");
                JMenuItem quit = new JMenuItem("Quit");
                quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                        System.exit(0);
                        }
                    }
                );
                control.add(quit);
            JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
                JMenuItem support = new JMenuItem("Support");
                JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
                    about.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                            //HERE!
                            Main.aboutWindow.setVisible(true);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                help.add(support);
                help.add(about);
            menubar.add(control);
            menubar.add(windows);
            menubar.add(help);
        controlpanel.setJMenuBar(menubar);
    controlpanel.setVisible(true);
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks. But i think its a little bit different. I have just added the entire source code, hopefully it will make my situation more clear.

Comment: thank you. It works. But it also caused another problem. I wanted to apply a placeholder `JLabel`, before adding any useful stuff.
But when i added it, the menubar disappeared. Anything i'm missing?
 `Main.aboutWindow.add(menubar);
    JLabel name = new JLabel("kingfisher");
    aboutWindow.add(name);
    Main.aboutWindow.setVisible(false);
 }`

Comment: Maybe adding both the 'menubar' and the `JLabel` to a (newly created) `JPanel`, and then adding just this `JPanel` to the `aboutWindow` could work. I'm not sure.

Comment: Idk if i understand u right, but if i do, thats something worth considering.
Maybe another time. Right now, the problem was solved. I had simply used `add(menubar)`, instead of using `setJMenuBar(menubar)`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `aboutWindow` is a local variable which is declared in the method named `about`. A simple approach to make `aboutWindow` visible to code from other methods (like the one shown in your question) is to declare it as a field. For that, move the declaration out of the `about` method.

Comment: Ok, that helped. But it seemingly caused another problem:
In aboutWindow, there is a menu bar and a label. Before, it worked (in an ugly solution that was putting everything into main). Now, when i un-comment the label, the menu bar disappears.

Comment: I don't have enough information to help with that, but I think you start to learn important lessons like "where to declare stuff" and "how to get access to internals". This, actually, is one of the more important aspects of programming. Enjoy learning :)

Comment: @sam4ritan if this answer was helpful to you, please consider clicking the tick button to accept it. Thanks!